# Databinding/Live data handle configuration changes with Retrofit/Rxjava

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java2, mutablelivedata

Please look at this code:

Main activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MutableLiveData<User> mutableUser = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mutableUser.setValue(new User("John","Gordon","Homeless"));

        activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        activityMainBinding.setHandler(new MainActivityHandler());

        activityMainBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        activityMainBinding.setUser(mutableUser);

        setSupportActionBar(activityMainBinding.toolbar);
    }
```

`MutableLiveData` is defined in xml layout:

`<variable name="user" type="android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;test.databindingtemplate.ViewModels.User&gt;"/`>

Each field from user is bound to control with data binding:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="@={user.firstName}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewSecondName"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewSecondName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

This works fine, configuration changes are tracked and populated to gui (for example, when I type something in "Name" field, value persists when screen rotates).

Next, I want to implement refreshing user details from rest webservice - Retrofit/RxJava and I want to show busy indicator while data loading is in progress, for example, in `onCreate` method:

```
showBusyIndicator(); 
testService.getUserDetails(headers)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(user ->
                {
                  hideBusyIndicator();
                  activityMainBinding.getUser().setValue(user);
                }, throwable -> 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ERROR loading user");
                    hideBusyIndicator();
                });
```

Now I'm not sure how to handle configuration changes properly - when busy indicator is shown, it should be recreated after screen rotation changes. As `MutableLiveData` handles configuration changes nicely, I am unable to find any solution (other than "classic" way) to solve my problem with loading indicator and handle result in this case.

Can you point me right direction?

[edit]
getUserDetails declaration:

```
@NonNull
@GET("/user")
Observable<User> getUserDetails(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
```

@user8035311

I modified your github sample to trigger simulated data loading on button click, this way (button has been added to layout):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        this.progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        final ActivityMainBinding mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        mainBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        mainBinding.button2.setOnClickListener(view ->
        {
            RxViewModel.RxViewModelFactory factory = new RxViewModel.RxViewModelFactory();
            final RxViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this, factory).get(RxViewModel.class);
            LiveData<User> liveData = model.getLiveData();
            progressDialog.show();
            liveData.observe(MainActivity.this, s ->
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                mainBinding.setUser(s);
            });

        });
    }
```

But this does not work. Task is interrupted on screen rotation, with exception:

> 06-27 09:05:18.737
>   11829-11829/app.rxrotation.com.architecturecomponentsrxrotation
>   E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   app.rxrotation.com.architecturecomponentsrxrotation.MainActivity has
>   leaked window DecorView@5b16e38[] that was originally added here
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:485)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
>           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
>           at app.rxrotation.com.architecturecomponentsrxrotation.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$1$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:35)
>           at app.rxrotation.com.architecturecomponentsrxrotation.MainActivity$$Lambda$0.onClick(Unknown
>   Source:4)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

After I click button second time, data loading not even executed.

Comment: Why not to use CompositeDisposable by subscribing to a task in onResume and clearing it in onPause?

Comment: Can you show me some example?

Comment: I modified my sample code (only single user loaded from rest service), to simplify it. `getUserDetails` is Retrofit interface method, nothing special is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `ViewModel` with `LiveData` to preserve your async tasks after config change. So, your `LiveData` could look like this:

```
public class UserLiveData extends LiveData<User> {
    public UserLiveData() {
        setValue(new User());
    }

    public UserLiveData(Headers headers) {
        Observable<User> observable = Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<? extends User>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<? extends User> call() throws Exception {
                User user = testService.getUserDetails(headers);
                return Observable.just(user);
            }
        });

        observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DefaultObserver<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(User value) {
                    setValue(value);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, your `UserDetailsViewModel` is the following:

```
public class UserDetailsViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<User> userLiveData;

    public UserDetailsViewModel() {
        userLiveData = new UserLiveData();    
    }

    public void observeLiveDate(LifecycleOwner owner,
                              Observer<User> observer) {
        userLiveData.observe(owner, observer);
    }

    public void loadLiveData(Headers headers) {
        userLiveData = new UserLiveData(someArgs);
    }
}
```

And then your `MainActivity` could be as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private UserViewModel viewModel;
    private ActivityMainBinding mainBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        this.progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
            R.layout.activity_main);
        mainBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

        observeLiveData();
        mainBinding.button2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            viewModel.initLiveData(<your headers>);
            observeLiveData();
        });
    }

    private void observeLiveData() {
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        viewModel.observeRxLiveDate(this, user -> {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            mainBinding.setUser(user);
        });
    }
}
```

I created a very simple example [here](https://github.com/Tester2012/architecturecomponentsrxrotation)

Comment: Interesting approach, I will test and eventually accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry, not yet tried, unfortunately I'm busy with other projects :(

Comment: In my real project I have 20 or 30 webservice calls, with this approach I will need to create 2 classes for each call. Is there any way to avoid boilerplate code like this? Also, won't task exection be interrupted on config change? I assume I need to add busy indicator hide in `onChanged`, but how to recreate it after config changes?

Comment: @user1209216 it's a more difficult question:). I'll try to come up with an example.

Comment: Is it possible to use Retrofit RxJava integration? In your sample you assumed Retrofit method is called synchronously. Also, it could be good to observe task start (to show busy indicator + recreate it on rotation changed without interrupting task execution) + task end/error (to hide busy indicator)

Comment: Also, is it possible to bind your RxViewModel using data binding? Just to avoid `textView.setText` etc and bind controls to view model instead.

Comment: @user1209216 1) Is your Retrofit method called async? Can it be changed to sync? 2) Do you want to show your progress indicator if at least one of the webservice calls is running? 3) RxViewModel can be bound but I need to introduce it in my sample then.

Comment: Retrofit2 supports sync and async calls. It also supports rxjava integration (as shown in my question), your proposal is to don't use rxjava integration from retrofit and call method synchronously instead and return value immediately, just asking. Regarding to progress indicator, I want single webservice call to have its own progress indicator. DataBinding sample will be really appreciated

Comment: BTW I also need to pass some data from main activity (it could be via viewmodel bound to edit control), then call webvsercice method and observe: start (to show busy indicator), end (to hide busy indicator), call result should be bound to control, task execution should survive rotation. So it's actaully quite common behaviour, as I can see, not so simple to implement though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173812/discussion-between-user8035311-and-user1209216).

Comment: @user1209216 I updated my sample on github. Please check it out and let me know if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Hello. How can I pass value from main activity to my method to be executed (this will we synchronous webservice call). Actually, I need 2 ways, pass any variable as parameter, second way, value got from text edit (I think, edit text should be bound to pass value automatically).

Comment: Another problem is there, qustion modified

Comment: @user1209216 1) I added an example for a button click 2) You can pass your arguments via ViewModel constructor (I also added it). 3) For me, there's no crash in the sample. Did you add anything else?

Comment: Thanks, it works. But, again... problem. I wanted to test start loading with button only, so I removed `observeLiveData();` from `onCreate` method, it's still present in button click handler. Now, after button click, again task does not survive configuration change (like screen rotation and I don't understand why?

Comment: Hi. I did not see your last comment, now it works :) Time to analyze how exactly does it work. Anyway, question answered, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ok, if I may ask last time... now, edit text content is erased on config change, how to fix that? Thanks

Comment: Well, I added `mainBinding.setUser(new User())` and it does not reset anymore. I actually dont want user to be recreated, y initial question had MutableLiveData included, now not needed? I believe MutableLive data is more elegant way (instsad of onSaveInstanceStade)